# Password validation with pydantic

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-re, pydantic

To avoid using an *if*-*else* loop, I did the following for adding password validation in [Pydantic](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic).

```py
    @field_validator("password")
    def check_password(cls, value):
        # Convert the password to a string if it is not already
        value = str(value)

        # Check that the password meets the criteria
        if len(value) < 8:
            raise ValueError("Password must have at least 8 characters")

        if not any(c.isupper() and c.islower() and c.isdigit() and c in string.punctuation for c in value):
            raise ValueError("Password must have at least one uppercase letter, one lowercase letter, and one digit")

        return value
```

But unfortunately that `if not any` condition is not working correctly. How can I fix it?

Comment: Obligatory: [XKCD 936](https://xkcd.com/936/).

Comment: Is regex an option for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no character that is simultaneously upper, lower, a digit, and a punctuation.

You need:

```
if not any(c.isupper() for c in value) or \
   not any(c.islower() for c in value) or \
   not any(c.isdigit() for c in value) or \
   not any(c in punctionation for c in value): 
  ... handle bad password ...
```